# Hadoop streaming c++ getTaskId

Tags: c++, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I've been trying to find a way to get (or pass) the taskId to my mapper in c++. I'm using hadoop streaming. So far I just got how to get it in Java. I need the task ID because I'm trying to write a file to HDFS, I'm using libhdfs c, but when I try to append concurrently it fails, because of the lease. Otherwise I'll have to change all my code to Java.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that instead of using Hadoop Streaming, I could use Hadoop Pipes to get the taskID. However, I was not able to print to HDFS, so I changed my InputFormat/RecordReader and used the key received in the mapper to create files with different names.